# C# Visual Studio Form, Can't Reset Timer

Tags: c#, forms, timer

Dispose isn't working in my code for some reason. When i hit the reset button, and then start again, it won't start the timer over. I've tried disabling and reenablinig enabled(), but it still didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class StopWatch : Form
    {
        bool reSet = false;
        bool stopped = true;
        public StopWatch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void startStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timer1.Enabled = true;
            if (stopped == true)
            {
                timer1.Start();
                stopped = false;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                stopped = true;
            }

        }

        private void reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Dispose();
            txtBox.Text = "";
            reSet = true;
            stopped = true;

        }
        int i = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBox.Text = i.ToString();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A timer isn't a stopwatch; timers tick at measured intervals, stopwatches conceptually take note of the time you press start and show the difference between the times when you press stop. You could implement a stopwatch using a timer to update the display of the watch to make it seem like it's counting time pass, but you wouldn't need to dispose anything and you don't need a timer - a stopwatch can work off dates alone

Comment: `Dispose` (generally) means **I am finished with this thing**. If you ever think "I plan to dispose this thing and then keep using it" then, fundamentally, you are on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the timer for now, just make a stopwatch:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.MinValue; //it's reset

StartButton_Click(...){
  startTime = DateTime.Now;
}

StopButton_Click(...){
  MessageBox.Show("counted secs: " + (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds);
}
```

That's a stopwatch

Now let's make it look like it runs. Add a label to the Form. Add a timer to the form, set it's interval to 100, enable it and put a tick event:

```
Timer_Tick(...){
  StopWatchLabel.Text = startTime == DateTime.MinValue ? "00:00:00.000" : (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString();
}
```

*Now* you can get into the minutiae of adding a reset button (set startTime to MinValue) starting and stopping the timer (no point updating a label to 00:00 ten times a second, but no harm in it either) but hopefully this proves that the timer is not (and should not) be part of the stopwatch function of measuring the passage of time. The timer doesn't need messing with/disposing etc. It's purely to update a label with the period that has passed since your start time

Comment: '''(startTime == DateTime.MinValue?'''  Did you mean for the ? to be a )

Comment: No, but I did add an unnecessary bracket at the other end! In english, this line of code means `set stopwatch text equal to: (if start time is equal to minvalue) then ("0:00:00") otherwise (a string representing the time between startTIme and now)`

Comment: Oh, it doesn't look like the parentheses are balanced. What does the question mark do?

Comment: it's an "inline if" - it tests something, and if the test it true, returns one value otherwise returns another value. In VB, which you might think is more readable, it would be `text = If(a=b,"it's true", "it's false")`. In C#, that's `text = a==b ? "it's true" : "it's false"`. The truth of a==b is evaluated, then either the true value or false value is chosen, and assigned per the `=` like you'd expect. Could also be written like `if(startTime == DateTime.MinValue) StopWatchLabel.Text = "0:00:00"; else StopWatchLabel.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString();` but that's far longer

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to C#